# angular-ui navbar is not supported?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I see that bootstrap navbar is missing in angular-ui(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).  Should I still refer to native bootstrap library to have a navbar in place?

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Comment: Err, "yes"? Navbar is just CSS

Comment: Depends . if you do not use any dropdown lists...but I think by default bootstrap library depends on the jquery library which would defeat the purpose of angular-ui.

Comment: Dropdowns are completely separate to navbar and are also covered by ui-bootstrap

Comment: Agree. I see that adding a bootstrap navbar can be done by jus referencing bootstrap.css without referring to bootstrap.js and so jquery. But I feel that such simple nav bar should have been there in angular-ui. Also, to avoid adding bootstrap package just for css,

Comment: You always [need Bootstrap CSS with ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started). If you're using Bower, you can just install the `bootstrap-css-only` lib to avoid the jQuery plugins